# Leaving Private Beta, and Initial Pro-Tempore Moderator Election!

Tags: discussion, beta, election, announcements

**Congratulations! You've met the participation and engagement expectations for an active private beta site, and will be moving into public beta on June 27th!**

As we’re getting ready to wrap up the private beta for Programming Language Design & Implementation Stack Exchange, that means it’s time to schedule your first pro-tem moderator election!

[On week 2 of your private beta](https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297/initial-moderator-election-community-interest-check?cb=1), I walked you through the process and what qualities a moderator ideally has, and some of you expressed your willingness to run in the initial election. As such, I’m focusing on the election timeline in this post.

### The timeline:

- Starting on June 27th, users can nominate themselves on the [election page](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/election/1). Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On July 4th, if there are 4 or more candidates, the election will move into the voting phase. If not, I'll extend the nomination period for a week. If, at the end of that extension period there are still less than 4 candidates, I'll simply appoint the candidates. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year).)
- If the election moves into the voting phase, I'll announce the results on meta on July 11th (or July 18th, if we need to extend the nomination period).

If you have any questions about the process, please ask them in an answer below.

And congratulations, once again!

Comment: "If you have any questions about the process, please ask them in an answer below." I like this inversion/subversion of the site mechanic :)

Answer (score 2):

From Area 51's FAQ:

> At any point after being in public beta for 6 months, if the site has
> at least 1000 open questions, 70% of which have at least one upvoted
> answer, the Community Team will coordinate with the community to start
> the process of removing the site’s beta label.

However, this doesn't seem to be completely true. I found Substrate and Polkadot SE which has met all of these, but I see nothing about removing the beta label. Also, then whats the Area51 stats for?

Comment: The A51 stats for seeing the health of a site; most sites don't meet all the requirements in A51 when they leave private beta/graduate

Comment: Not even the Area51 sats (those are 10 QPD, 2.5 Answer ratio, etc.) these are the "actual" graduation requirements @Seggan-OnStrike