# What happens if a recently banned user tries to run for moderator?

Tags: discussion, election

I cannot run for moderator here because I got [temporarily banned](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) on Meta for a week less than a year ago for doing [questionable things](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390635/1370400). But what would happen if I tried, presumably there would be some error message, but what would that look like?

Comment: I think this is a question better suited for mother meta, since it's not specific to our site. You could also answer this question yourself by trying to run and grabbing a screenshot

Comment: Seems like there is an established policy on this, described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274114/1135948) on main Meta.

Comment: So your account was suspended from asking questions because you asked too many poor-quality questions, then you deleted the account and made a new one to circumvent the question suspension, then got a full suspension for doing that? Ideally you would still be able to participate in the democracy as a candidate, and if PLDI users think your questions are poor in quality, they can vote accordingly. **The rule banning you from running in the election is undemocratic.**

Comment: Completly agree as I think that I would have gotten a reasonable amount of mod votes and my suspension for one comment @NikeDattani

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Leaving Private Beta, and Initial Pro-Tempore Moderator Election!](https://langdev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379/leaving-private-beta-and-initial-pro-tempore-moderator-election) In the body, it is mentioned, " (There's a small chance we'll need to remove a nomination.)" with a link to the post that kaya3 linked above.

Comment: Of course it doesn't because it does actually say when it will stop you @Isaiah

Comment: This is not a duplicate and duplicate closing has been rejected repeatdly. Stop spamming the queue in the hopes of closing this

Answer (score 3):

So, I’m currently suspended on meta for a rude comment so I couldn’t run for moderator either. Just saying, you couldn’t run for mod even if you were not suspended since you would need to have 300+.

So, I clicked the nomination button and then it let me in just fine. Then I typed in a nice little nomination (thinking it that the not suspended might no longer apply) and entered it. It worked. I even had the third best candidate score of 6/40 and I think there was a chance I could have been elected.

But I couldn’t seem to find any policy saying it was actually allowed so I silently removed my nomination. And that was the end of my first run to become a moderator.

Comment: Meta is known for over-using the "suspend user" button, as many users have publicly shown what comment got them suspended, and usually they are quite mild. If you don't mind sharing, what was your comment? Perhaps we could at least show our support if we believe you were suspended wrongly.

Comment: It was "Why me no get well grammar" @NikeDattani

Comment: @NikeDattani Users are rarely suspended for a single comment. It's usually a pattern.

Comment: This was one comment, thats it. And on meta its not rare @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil'

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' do you have statistics to back up your claim?

Answer (score 2):

This is what happens:
[image: Banned recently]

Comment: But if you click outside the white box it lets you submit a nomination